# Binded DataGridView only updating the currently selected row

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I'm working on getting my DataGridView controls to auto update the values of my objects in my object model. I have object arrays that I'm binding to my DataGridView through the following code

```
    Dim bs As BindingSource = New BindingSource()
    bs.DataSource = aryJoints
    DataGridJoints.DataSource = bs
```

I am raising events in the object model using INotifyPropertyChanged.
The following is in my "Public Class Joint"

```
    Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
```

And in the GoalPosition property I have the following:

```
    Private _GoalPosition As Double

    Property GoalPosition() As Double

        Get
            Return _GoalPosition
        End Get

        Set(ByVal Value As Double)
            _GoalPosition = Value

            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("GoalPosition"))

        End Set

    End Property
```

If I update the property aryJoints(0).GoalPosition from the same form or other forms the DataGridView will only update the GoalPosition field in the DataGridView when that row is selected. If I'm on a different row and then move onto the row that had a change, then the row updates with the latest values.

From my understanding, once I've done proper binding with events being raised any cell should auto update with new values. I shouldn't have to be in that cell, or have that row selected for the form to reflect the changes.

If I call DataGridJoints.Refresh() the DataGridView updates all values as it should. But the whole point of creating binded DataSources is to avoid the need to call .refresh. There will be many forms and operations updating the object model from different places and I need the DataGridViews on the various forms to auto update themselves.

What am I missing a step or doing wrong?

Comment: `DataGridView.Refresh()` doesnt do anything regarding the data; it just repaints the control.  I assume that `aryJoints` is an array of that `Joint` class?  You ought not need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you wrap it in a `BindingSource`.  The user can only edit the current cell, so are you asking about changes made to the data are not showing up?

Comment: >> I assume that aryJoints is an array of that Joint class? 
Yes, that is correct.

The data is being updated by code. The user is not allowed to change data in the DataGridView. So for instance, A user is moving a scroll bar that changes data in the Joint class and that data should be showing up in the DataGridView, but it will only update on rows that are currently selected.

Comment: I should add, the data is also updated from other sources. Other forms. Other routines, etc. There can be 7 rows of joints for instance that are all being updated in the object model. The DataGridView should be updating them automatically. Thanks.

Comment: Is there are particular reason you are using an array?  If you use a `BindingList(Of Joint)` it will work fine and you can elide the BindingSource as well.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: ...scratch the part about not needing `INotifyPropertyChanged` I was thinking of something else

Comment: The aryJoints is looped through in dozens of places in the code. It is how I have been accessing the Joints in the object model. When I load the object model, I load an array of the Joints. It was the best way I could see to manage the code. I will research BindingList as it is new to me. I will research if it is a better approach, but it may not change the code much, as I am still just creating loops to walk through the list or array. If it solves this particular issue, then there is that obvious advantage.

Comment: >>>Please read How to Ask. Is there something wrong in my post? I have read how to ask and posted the most clear and concise question possible. I've also read many other similar posts and the answers do say that the DataGridView should be updating from the way the code is written. Hence, my posting.

Comment: *...and take the [tour]*  It explains how SO works beyond getting answers.  Lists/BindingLists can be used in a loop, so how it is created should be the only change needed (maybe the name - thats why screwing the datatype into vars names went out of fashion long ago).

Comment: By the by, if you are using a BindingSource, you should add, remove and update using your BS and/or use `ResetBindings` to update the display. A BindingList eliminates the need for all that cruft and it is what it is meant for.

Comment: I did a quick test implementation of a BindingList and it does indeed update rows that are not currently selected. So that is awesome. Still leaves the original question out there, but I'm happy to find a different way to implement the code. Since BindingList can be looped through just like the arrays I'll likely switch over. The code is essentially the same. Thank you for the solution. If you post it as an official answer I can check it off as a solution.

Comment: Per the ResetBindings... That is the same as doing a DataGridView.Refresh, which I cannot. This program is talking to robots over serial ports and I cannot hang the program waiting for serial responses in order to call refresh code. Hence the whole need to allow the DataGridView to auto update when the new information comes back in on it's own time. Which the solution of switching to BindingList does. The serial packet comes in and updates the model. Boom, the DataGridView auto updates as needed.

Comment: ResetBindings will just act on the display of the datasource data in the DGV; its not going to trigger something else somewhere to annoy the robots unless you have that kind of code in the Getters/Setters - but it will refresh the entire list which can be undesirable when it is long.

Comment: Right, I get that. It is that I don't know "when" to call it. In order to do timing I would have to either wait in the main thread (super bad), or call it from the secondary responding thread (forcing a full refresh, also bad). Which is what I'm trying to avoid. Doing full refreshes on form controls or datasets murders the program. There are hundreds of calls coming and going to the robots. Hence the need to set up the code right so it just updates the cell in the DGV when one piece of data changes. Which it looks like will work using a BindingList versus the array :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments above to try switching over to BindingList instead of using a binded array. I tested this solution and it works. The DataGridView updates as needed on any row when the object model has updated values. So I will implement this change in the code :)